# How to execute a java script with jshell?

Tags: java, shebang, java-9, jshell

Given that Java 9 is upon us and we can finally have a java REPL with `jshell` I was hoping there was a way to add a shebang to a script and have `jshell` interpret it.

I tried creating `test.jsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jshell -s
System.out.println("Hello World")
/exit
```

However that gives:

```
⚡ ./test.jsh
|  Error:
|  illegal character: '#'
|  #!/usr/bin/env jshell -s
|  ^
|  Error:
|  illegal start of expression
|  #!/usr/bin/env jshell -s
|    ^
Hello World
```

It turns out there is an enhancement request for this in OpenJDK https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167440.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use

`//usr/bin/env jshell --show-version --execution local "$0" "$@"; exit $?`

as the first line of `test.jsh`. The `test.jsh` script could look like:

```
//usr/bin/env jshell --show-version "$0" "$@"; exit $?
System.out.println("Hello World")
/exit
```

The command line option `--show-version` is optional, of course, but gives immediate feedback that the tool is running.

The *extra* command line option `--execution local` prevents `jshell` to spawn another VM. This speeds up launch time and if an exception is thrown by your script code, the local VM will exit.

Consult the output of `jshell --help` and `jshell --help-extra` for more options.

**Update**

Also take a look at https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang *Having fun with Java scripting*, which offers a neat wrapper around running `.java` files from the command line.

Comment: How does this even work? I wonder how portable this is. Granted that `#!` isn't standard POSIX anyway but surely as far as magic numbers go it would be the most widely adopted.

Comment: At least `bash` supports the inital `//` line. See this thread for details http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/kulla-dev/2016-October/thread.html#1679 ... with Brian Goetz stating that making a `.jsh` file executable _ is trying to turn jshell into something it wasn't designed for._

Comment: > _How does this even work?_
See the description of the "hack" at section _"Mimic the shebang via Bash"_ at http://golangcookbook.com/chapters/running/shebang/

Comment: Just got to try this with ZSH and it also works, although I had to use `usr/bin/env jshell` instead and quote the variable expansions. Much nicer output than my answer.

Comment: I added the **ZSH** example without testing it. Is it: `//usr/bin/env jshell --show-version "$0" "$@"; exit $?`

Comment: Yeah although that should be the same for BASH too? The changes are more likely because I don't have JAVA_HOME set and the quotes are just to handle spaces correctly.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a cop out by Brian Goetz. I think it should have been designed for that. Groovy and Scala both support this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148445/discussion-between-sormuras-and-steiny).

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that with a bit of trickery there is a way, although I haven't fully managed to suppress the interpreted commands but pretty close to what I want.

Change `test.jsh` to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
tail -n +4 "$0" | jshell -s "$@"
exit $?
System.out.println("Hello World")
/exit
```

Which gives us:

```
⚡ ./test.jsh
-> System.out.println("Hello World")
Hello World
-> /exit
```

Answer (score 4):

The below works too; put it into a `someScript.jsh` file and run it with `./someScript.jsh`. All arguments received by `someScript.jsh` will go to `String[] args`.

```java
#!/home/gigi/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java --source 11

import java.util.Arrays;
import ro.go.adrhc.*; // example of using your classes, e.g. App below

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do whatever you want here, e.g.:
        // System.out.println("Hello World");
        // or
        // use a class:
        // App.main(args);
        // e.g. from ro.go.adrhc package, by running:
        // CLASSPATH="/path-to-ro.go.adrhc-classes" ./someScript.jsh 
    }
}
```

The usage of the wrapping class, here `X`, is a mandatory trick for this to work. Use the Java version you have by changing `/home/gigi/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java`.
Inspired by https://blog.codefx.org/java/scripting-java-shebang/.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by steiny answer, I came up with a more generic solution

https://gist.github.com/ffissore/012d7e32a096fde5266f49038c93dcaf

In essence: `jshell-wrapper` will strip the first line of the script (which is supposed to be the shebang) and will add a `/exit` at the end of the script

Comment: nice script but would work 2 of it started in parallel?

Comment: they would be 2 different processes, so why not

Comment: I'm thinking about the usage of `TMP='mktemp'` which seems to be a file in the end used by many threads each one possible with different jsh files.

Comment: `mktemp` creates a new file each time it's called

Comment: you are right; now I notice it’s not a name but the execution of mktemp